# How to import shapefile into SQL Server 2008 R2 using only SQL scripts?

Tags: shapefile, sql-server

I am trying to import some shapefiles into SQL Server 2008 R2. I found this useful tool called [Shape2SQL](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools.aspx) however I am not sure how I can import shapefile directly using only SQL scripts as this is important for build automation and deployment. So far I haven't found anything useful just yet.

Would anyone be able to point some directions?

Comment: I found shp2sqlserver which I am giving it a try. http://code.google.com/p/cumberland/wiki/shp2sqlserver

Comment: shp2sqlserver is only in alpha and has great limitations so far which isn't suitable for me.

From the website quote: This is alpha level software. I have loaded some complex shapefiles up to 20MB with it, but it could bomb on yours.
The Shapefile loader only supports Point, Polyline, Polygon, and there associated *M types (measurement value is ignored)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would equate this to asking for a SQL script that imported an excel file to SQL Server.  Even if it *were* possible, you would be better off if you *did not* use only SQL scripts to automate the deployment of information.

Its like asking for a screwdriver to hammer in a nail.  SQL Server doesn't understand things like shapefile format and excel spreadsheets because that's not what a DBMS is for: it's what [DTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transformation_Services) and/or [SSIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver16) is for.

To answer your question, however, GDAL has been the DTS of spatial information for quite some time now. Have a look at the following command to import spatial information to SQL Server using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=spatial;trusted_connection=yes" "TG20.shp"
```

GDAL Binaries (Assuming Windows) are available from [this list](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) ([via](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries)).  You can install according to [this process](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/), but you should ignore the steps about python.

After installing GDAL, just modify the connection string and data source in the above command to suit your needs.  Note that ogr2ogr also supports multiple other formats.

Comment: By GDAL you mean this link? http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

Comment: I found this blog post useful after learning the keyword GDAL from @Geoist's answer. http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/opening-ms-sql-server-2008-spatial-tables-in-qgis-correctly/

Comment: And I am using ogr2org from OSGeo4W Windows installer. https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: OSGeo4W is highly recommended, although a bit more complicated to manage IMO.

Comment: Tried a few standlone gdal windows binaries and found OSGeo4W Windows installer works the best (for my situation now at least). Thanks.

Comment: I suggest an edit to refer to SSIS, rather than DTS, as DTS is very old technology (pre-SQL Server 2005), but this was rejected. Be aware if you want to do anything with SQL Server, you need to look for SSIS