# How to save a vector layer from QGIS to Sql Server 2008 or 2012?

Tags: qgis, sql-server, qgis-plugins

using QGIS, i've loaded up some [administrative boundary data of New Zealand](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). I wish to now import this vector data from QGIS into my Sql Server 2012.

Is there any way to do this with QGIS 1.8.0-Lisboa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can do it directly with QGIS but [Shape2SQL](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/shape2sql.aspx) ( free standalone tool ) can do it for you.

[image]

You can also [import shapefiles to SQL Server using ogr2ogr](http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/importing-spatial-data-to-sql-server-with-ogr2ogrnow-even-easier/). A sample command is:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=spatial;trusted_connection=yes" "your_shapefile.shp"
```

Source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29849/292

Comment: I've tried that (so many times) but it failed (with the administrative dataset from that link).

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: exe crashed. yep -> stack trace, dump, etc. I might try the ogr2ogr method. Where can i find it? (i've installed QGIS, remember). *Assumption* : it's included with the stock standard QGIS 1.8 windows install.

Comment: You can try adding the GDAL directory to your Windows path. Once you've done that, you can invoke the command on the command prompt (cmd.exe)